# Big security problem in Nautilus 3.28.1

Tags: linux, security, gnome, root, nautilus

In my Arch Linux installation with Gnome 3.28, I recently noticed that I can enter with Nautilus in the private directory /root and see the files inside while Nautilus is started without root rights. In addition I can create directories everywhere in the filesystem as a non-root user when I start nautilus like this :

> $ nautilus admin:///

How is it possible while Nautilus do not have the root rights ? For the moment, it's a very strange security hole for me...

Comment: Do you have a NFS share on your machine? What happens if you run the command `ping admin`?

Comment: No I haven't any NFS filesystem on my machine but when I run the `ping admin` command, I get this : `64 bytes from assistance.tech.numericable.fr (82.216.111.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=17.5 ms`

Comment: It should ask for either the root password or your own password, depending on your system’s setup; but it will use cached authentication tokens if they are available (again depending on setup). Have you tweaked `pkexec` & co.?

Comment: No i haven't tweaked that but when I run `pkexec` it directly starts a root shell without asking me for any password...

Comment: Did you check it really doesn't have root rights? Something like suid bit set?

Comment: The command `nautilus admin:///` tries to access via Nautilus the NFS server "admin", not your local machine. "admin" must be another machine in your domain, or something defined in your `/etc/hosts` file. When you say "I can create directories everywhere in the filesystem" have you checked that it's really the filesystem of your local machine?

Comment: It's the real filesystem on admin:/// because I can find my home directory in /home.The nautilus binary has no suid bit set (it has rwxr-xr-x rights). When I run `ps aux` I can see that Nautilus run with a non-root account

Comment: `assistance.tech.numericable.fr` has a web server open to the world, even if it returns a 403. Not good.

Comment: I have verified but there is absolutly no nfs client or server on my arch linux machine but I think the problem comes from polkit : a user with no root right or sudo rights can start a complete root shell on my machine just by typing `pkexec` and without having to enter any password. It's very strange

Comment: When i do so, I'm prompted for sudoers account, if you put in your sudoer file that you don't need password I think that's normal.

Comment: I will ask, what has been asked before but not answered. Can you verify that when you add a file/directory, that this file starts to exist on **your** machine.

Comment: Yes it starts to exist but check my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by an insecure configuration of the sudo system. When I installed my Arch Linux system and to have the hability to execute commands without the root account, I added directly my username in the sudoers file like this :

```
martin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

It worked very well with sudo but not at all with polkit. With this configuration, when I just typed `pkexec` in my shell, it opened a root shell without asking me for any password. But when Nautilus tries to access the `/root` directory, he execute the `pkexec` command. So that I could go in this directory without any password with my normal user account.

To correct the problem, I put my user in the `wheel` group and uncomment this line in the sudoers file

```
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

In conclusion, it's not a security breech in Nautilus but an insecure configuration I made...I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Linx/Unix working as it should. System `root` files are *not* invisible, but they should be off-limits for writing. And some files you can see, but not read (e.g. `/etc/shadow`).

Comment: OP said `/root` not `/`